# Discard the loging Screen

Tags: java, android

I have developed a simple android application which user have to login with a login page and he will be redirect to the home page.But my problem is when i press back button from the home page it again redirected to the login page .But I don't want to see the login page.I want to exit from the application when the back button is pressed from the home page.How can i do this.Can someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

Call `finish` in your login activity before you start your home activity. You cannot return to a finished activity

Answer (score 0):

In LoginPageActivity call `finish()` after starting `Intent` with HomePageActivity so the LoginPage wont be held in back stack

```
public void startHomeActivity() {

    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the login activity call finish() just after starting the Intent that redirect to the home page. Calling finish only if the login in completed correctly, remove the current login activity from the android stack and the new home activity will be proposed to the user.

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, newactivity.class);
finish();
```

Give a look to the [activity lifecycle](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDkQygQwAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ProcessLifecycle&ei=w3atUtCuIpGVyQOtl4G4Dw&usg=AFQjCNEVbcf_xF52Np66Qp881y0W1JzaTQ&sig2=GyTJGbPEXqDOSDs-gHFIAA&bvm=bv.57967247,d.bGQ)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Do this to start your HomeActivity from your LoginActivity

`startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class)
.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP));`